# Use ajax to check if an URL exists

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

i am trying to check if an url is online. I use the $new_url for the url that the user gives. The problem that i face is that i always take a 404 either the url is online either not...

```
<?php 
session_start();
$new_url=$_POST['url1'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
function isValidURL() {
 alert('<?php echo "ajax".$new_url;?>');
   $.ajax({
          url: "('<?php echo $new_url;?>')",

          success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
        //console.log(arguments);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        alert("11111");
        alert(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        alert("22222");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(textStatus);

    } 
});
}


var isValid = isValidURL();
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just do an AJAX call to another page on your domain which does the check, then responds with the status. You'll get into a whole mess with Same Origin stuff if you try to do it with Javascript on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect

```
url: "('<?php echo $new_url;?>')",
```

should be something like

```
url: "<?php echo $new_url;?>",
```

but then you'll have a problem with Same Origin Policy, for external urls.
Since your page already makes a round trip to the server, you should just check on the server side to see if the url exists.

Comment: I still taking a 404... as a url i use an facebook event page...for example www.facebook.com/107168247742. Any help?

Comment: I tried that and i take a 0 for (xhr.status) on both occasions (correct,false url..).

Comment: What do you mean, to check on the server side if the url exists? What i have to do?

Comment: You cannot use ajax to make requests to arbitrary urls, but in php you can, take a look at [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)